# how can i call a code behind method from javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel

hello guys i have w method that changes the opacity of an image using on click event and saves this image in a folder. what im trying to do is that i want to call this method  using onmouseup event and preview that img automatically in a div .
i have this code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional><ContentTemplate>
<input max="10" min="0" name="rangeInput" onmousemove="updateTextInput(this.value);" onmouseup="return showImg()" type="range" runat="server" />
<input id="txtOp" size="3" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="bntChangeOpacity" runat="server" onClick="bntChangeOpacity_Click1" Text="Change Opacity" />
        <div id="placehere"></div>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so here i want to replace the bntChangeOpacity_Click1 method to be called onmouseup event

the code behind :

```
public void bntChangeOpacity_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = txtOp.Value;
        float ss = float.Parse(s);
        float opacityvalue = ss / 10;
        var img = ImageTransparency.ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("img1.jpg")), opacityvalue);
        img.Save(Server.MapPath("img2.jpg"));

    }
```

Comment: use ajax http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/

Comment: search the following in google: asp.net call server side function from javascript ... you will be surprised how many good results are there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this as a webmethod innorder to call this from front end;change the method signature as like the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void bntChangeOpacity_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = txtOp.Value;
    float ss = float.Parse(s);
    float opacityvalue = ss / 10;
    var img = ImageTransparency.ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("img1.jpg")), opacityvalue);
    img.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("img2.jpg"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PageMethods` for that.
Make your method static and decorate it with `WebMethod` attribute as below

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ChangeOpacity()
    {
        string s = txtOp.Value;
        float ss = float.Parse(s);
        float opacityvalue = ss / 10;
        var img = ImageTransparency.ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("img1.jpg")), opacityvalue);
        img.Save(Server.MapPath("img2.jpg"));

    }
```

and call it like 
    function changeOpacity() {
      PageMethods.ChangeOpacity();
    }

from javascript.

you need to change `bntChangeOpacity` mark up as below.

```
<asp:Button ID="bntChangeOpacity" runat="server" onClientClick="changeOpacity()" Text="Change Opacity" />
```

Don't forget to use `ScriptManager` on page.

Answer (score 0):

Please find sample code of that

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript

Otherwise you need to do Ajaxcall.

Comment: This fits as a comment.not an answer